# HttpClient PostAsync does not return

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

I've seen a lot of question about this, and all points to me using ConfigureAwait(false), but even after doing so, it still doesn't returned any response. When I run the debugger, the code stops at the PostAsync and does not continue with my code. Am I doing something wrong here? Does it have to do with me calling an API via HTTPS?

Here's the code:

```
public async static Task<PaymentModel> AddAsync(Card card)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:", "hidden"))));

    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

    var cardJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(card);
    var postRequest = new StringContent(cardJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var request = await client.PostAsync(new Uri("https://sample-3rd-party-api/api/endpoint/here"), postRequest).ConfigureAwait(false);
    var content = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

EDIT:

In response to the comments below, the code is contained from a method AddAsync(Card card) called from a button click with a handler:

```
public async void OnExecute(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    //some code here
    payment = await PaymentModel.AddAsync(card).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

EDIT 2:
I tried pinging the API, but it returns a request timed out, but when I tried it using Postman, it's doing fine (the API is just a Sandbox which is open for all, so it's okay to share [this](http://developers.paymaya.com.payment-vault.s3-website-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/#tokenized-payments-paymenttokens-post)):
[image]

[image]

EDIT 3:

I think the problem lies with where I don't have an SSL certificate to access the API. I have a PHP server that connects to the same API and I have to set SSL_VERIFYPEER to false just so I can access it (don't worry, I added a cacert now so its on true again). Can the same issue be happening here? If so, what can I do to create a valid certificate for my xamarin forms app

Comment: Where and how are you calling all this? Please show us the containing method and the place where you are calling it.

Comment: `HttpClient` has a `Timeout` property, set it to a small value and wrap your code in a try-catch block to see if any exceptions.

Comment: as @FedericoDipuma is getting at, your problem (if it is a deadlock) will be with code calling this code, or code calling that code, etc. Somewhere you are blocking on an awaited synchronizaton context. ConfigureAwait was not created to avoid deadlocks and [it doesn't always save you](https://contrivedexample.com/2017/12/04/configureawait-sometimes-saves-the-day-everytime/), so you must understand what it does to use it correctly.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma hi, I have added the other code from the very topmost call. I hope it will shed light on what could cause the issue

Comment: @DannyChen I tried wrapping it on a try-catch block. It only resulted in a Thread Cancelled exception.

Comment: `HttpClient` throws `TaskCanceledException` when `Timeout` exceeded. Are you sure the third-party API is working?

Comment: @DannyChen yes, I was able to access it using Postman.

Comment: Try setting up Fiddler to intercept that request and sending the request again through C#. Compare what you capture there to what you can see about the request in Postman. If they are fully identical you know your issue is on the C# side of handling the response. If they are different you can adjust how you build the request in C#. If you don't see the request at all it's not even being sent and you'll have something else to look at in C#.

Comment: Could this be a firewall issue?

Comment: The Postman request you posted isn't using SSL. Does it still work when you do make the request over SSL?

Comment: Is PaymentModel.AddAsync comming from third party library ? Internally it still can use some async / await without .ConfigureAwait(..) which will cause the block on some frameworks like wpf, win forms, asp (not core) .. etc

Comment: AddAsync is an async method from my Model class PaymentModel

Comment: @ATerry yes, it works over SSL. I'm starting to think that thats the problem now. My PHP app is also trying to connect to the same API but it wouldnt work unless I provide a client certificate - the part I dont know how to make in Xamarin.

Comment: @lala The only time that I have seen this type of error was with SSL negotiation issues. My issue was with an upgrade to TLS1.2, but you have that covered. Requiring a client cert would certainly create the same SSL failure. Postman is probably pulling from your cert store while your code won't do that without specifying the cert location explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(card);
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var t = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("https://sample-3rd-party-api/api/endpoint/here", json);

    Response R =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>((JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(t.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.ToString())).ToString());
}
```

Comment: Don't dispose of HttpClient, because it is designed to be re-used. Here's some more information: https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Comment: HttpClient DOES NOT have 'PostAsJsonAsync'.

Answer (score 1):

What's most likely happening here is your `OnExecute` method has a return type of `void` instead of `Task` which prevents the UI thread from being able to await it. Try either changing that return type to `Task` or creating a new UI thread to perform this work. I wouldn't worry about the ping timing out as long as Postman works. Many public web servers disable their ping response.

Comment: But my OnExecute method is a button event handler (as per the docs, void is suitable for event handlers). Would it still work by changing the type to Task?

Comment: Also, I have an API set up on my azure site and it's responding just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and below trick fixed the issue.

Change your `var request = await client.PostAsync(...);` as below

```
var task = client.PostAsync(new Uri("https://sample-3rd-party-api/api/endpoint/here"), postRequest);
var request = task.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Does it have to do with me calling an API via HTTPS?

As you are remaining in the same network and calling the same API from POSTMAN and .NET HTTP Client and only getting success with POSTMAN.So this issue gets cancelled.
Next

> tried pinging the API, but it returns a request timed out

This is answered on top of mine.

Can you Please try setting the timeout option for HTTPClient while initializing.

```
client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
```

and if still Problem persists please setup Fiddler and compare both the req sent from POstman and .NET client

Comment: Hi, I think the problem lies with where I don't have an SSL certificate to access the API. I have a PHP server that connects to the same API and I have to set SSL_VERIFYPEER to false just so I can access it (don't worry, I added a cacert now so its on true again). Can the same issue be happening here? If so, what can I do to create a valid certificate for my xamarin forms app?

Comment: Well,I have worked with IIS and there we have a scope to create self signed certificate .I am sure that is a provision for PHP server too .

Answer (score 0):

So I think the problem is resolved now since I'm able to receive content from the request, what I did was simply follow the docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/transport-layer-security?tabs=windows

It looks like my settings are outdated in platform level.

> Update the HttpClient implementation and SSL/TLS implementation
>   options to enable TLS 1.2 security.
>
> Update the HttpClient Implementation option to enable TSL 1.2
>   security. (NSUrlSession (iOS 7.0+)