# C# Error get token oauth2 fom external dll

Tags: c#, dll, oauth-2.0

I have developed a DLL in C# to acquire an authentication token using OAuth2.
This library is utilized within a C# program.
When attempting to retrieve the token from the application, the library never responds. Through debugging, it has been observed that the process stalls at an 'await' instruction and never proceeds beyond that point.
Here I leave the function of the library where the code remains in a waiting state and never exits the await.

```
private async Task PerformTokenObtention()
{
    try
    {
        if (authorization_code != null)
        {
            string tokenPayload = $"grant_type=authorization_code" +
                                  $"&code={authorization_code}" +
                                  $"&client_id={clientInfo.client_id}" +
                                  $"&client_secret={clientInfo.client_secret}" +
                                  $"&redirect_uri={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(clientInfo.redirect_uri)}";

            HttpContent content = new StringContent(tokenPayload, Encoding.ASCII, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            
            // here the code are waiting forever
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(clientInfo.token_url, content);
            
            string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            // Process the response
            if (responseString != null && responseString.Contains("access_token"))
            {
                Token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenModel>(responseString);
                Token.HoraObtencionToken = DateTime.Now;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception($"Token retrieval failed: {responseString}");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Authorization code was not captured.");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

By the way, I'm calling the async function PerformTokenObtention with await

`await PerformTokenObtention();`

Any help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried using a cancellation token with a timeout in your PostAsync? Also - just as a side note and unrelated - you shouldn't be throwing a type of 'Exception' (ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22453825/685341)

Comment: The try-catch exception was only a test.
The timeout doesn't solve my problem, because I don't get the token anyway

Comment: The HttpClient should timeout by default after 100 seconds, not sure why that isn't working. The timeout in a cancellation token should cause the await to abort, which should address at least part of your problem. The reason why you are not getting a token back from some source you haven't cited is unlikely to be solvable here.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I find a solution from two answered questions

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/72909241/2171002
- [HttpClient - PostAsync doesn’t return](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59313010/2171002)

Here a fragment from my code with the modifications;

```
// HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(clientInfo.token_url, content);
var response = client.PostAsync(clientInfo.token_url, content);
var request = response.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
//string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
string responseString = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```